# Every time I am restarting my computer, it has deleted my work?

Tags: windows-8, laptop

I am facing a weird problem on my school laptop computer (Windows 8 PRO) and I am really hoping to get some help on this. It is every time when you have restarted the computer, all the files are gone, shortcuts to programs are also gone, and the background theme has changed back to old one and even the Goggle Chrome. It is like every time I doing something on the computer and restart it, the computer erase the changes or work I have made.

How can I stop it??

Please help me!

A small notice, my other classmate are facing the same problem and he is forced to save all his work on his USB every time he is doing some work on his computer.

As you can see on the first pic you can see the changes I have made on the computer/desktop, and when you log off or turn off the computer and turn it again, it are back to old/custom one (see the other pic)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Speak to your school's IT, they may be doing this on purpose.  Since this is a school-supplied notebook that you have no control over (presumably), then this is off-topic for SU, and we'd just be guessing what's causing it, when there are legitimate reasons/ways for an IT dept. to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You say this is a school's computer.  This behavior you are describing is probably intentional.  Your school most likely has implemented software that will revert the computer back to its original state after every reboot.  This is a safety & security feature, preventing the students from permanently altering and damaging the computer.  Most likely, they told you to save your work to USB drives for this reason.

Comment: I have actually experience this before at another school but my other classmates have not this problem at all besides the one mentioned in my text... it is kind of unfair for me at least. But I will try and talk to the school:)

Comment: Talk to the person in charge of the laptops.  If there is something different about yours, maybe there is a misconfiguration.